# converting python script into javascript code using Pyjs

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, pyjamas

I am trying to convert python script into a javascript code using the Pyjs.
 I have taken look at the Pyjs documentation, but I am still not quite sure how to make it happen...can someone guide me through?

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the pyjs examples? They're going to be your best resource...

http://pyjs.org/examples/